# Handling of Failure Status in HTTP OPTIONS - Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, error-handling, http-options-method

I tried to find out the solution for one of the existing question
[Error Handling in HTTP Ajax Call using $fetch Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45168087/error-handling-in-http-ajax-call-using-fetch-javascript) - I tried to reproduce the said scenario. I found the issue, that is the HTTP call triggers the **`HTTP OPTIONS`** method. Finally its not returning any HTTP Status code. I checked the Netwok, its shows an empty status code and the status signal is grayed

[image]

Refer Preflight Table Request: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/preflight-table-request

Kindly assist me how to handle the failure of **`HTTP OPTIONS`**

I tried the following code

```
$fetch("http://localhost:1000/SearchUsers?....")
.then(response => {
        if((response != undefined) && (response != null)) {
          if (response.status && (response.status === 200)) {
            alert('Super');
            return response.json();
          } else {
            alert('Hai');
            return '';
          } 
        } else {
          alert('Oooops');
          return '';
        }
      })
.catch(err => {
        const errStatus = err.response ? err.response.status : 500;
        if (errStatus === 404){
          alert("HTTP 404");
        } else {
          alert("Network or Internal Server Error");
        }
});
```

The above said code always executes the **`Catch`** block and it alerts the message `"Network or Internal Server Error"`.

I tried with following Header information too, but it fails.

```
headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, GET, PUT'
  }
```

Kindly assist me how to get the appropriate Error Status Code, in current scenario the requesting server is offline.

Comment: Ok, If the server is offline - how could I handle this Failure ? its not returning anything. could you please assist me.

Comment: @JaromandaX - I need to know the appropriate issue, for example Server is offline. But in current scenario I can't able to get any status code, so its blindly alerting the user with a message `"Network or Internal Server Error"`.

Comment: Yes, it will handle. But the said Server is offline. How it will handle ? moreover my expected HTTP Status Code is 404

Comment: @JaromandaX - yes I got your point and you are right. Then How could I diagnose this ? I having two scenarios - Locally Offline trying to access the online API - just switched off the wifi while on hitting the API (or) Locally Online but the requesting Server is Offline.

Comment: @JaromandaX - How could I conclude this case is a Network Issue in the Catch block.

Comment: @JaromandaX - Thanks a lot... I concluding the Response is `undefined`, then I'm considering it should be an Network Error.